# getting only the first Number from String in Python

Tags: python, string, numbers

I´m currently facing the problem that I have a string of which I want to extract only the first number. My first step was to extract the numbers from the string.

```
Headline = "redirectDetail('27184','2 -New-York-Explorer-Pass')"
print (re.findall('\d+', headline ))
Output is ['27184', '2']
```

In this case it returned me two numbers but I only want to have the first one "27184".

Hence, I tried with the following code:

```
 print (re.findall('/^[^\d]*(\d+)/', headline ))
```

But It does not work:

```
 Output:[]
```

Can you guys help me out? Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: `>>> re.search(r'\d+',Headline).group(0)
'27184'`

Comment: `print (re.findall(r'^[^\d]*(\d+)', headline ))`

Comment: You're using `findall`, which finds all the occurrences. By the way, Python regular expressions do not require `/` characters.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys. Great, it worked

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just use `re.search` which stops matching once it finds a match.

```
re.search(r'\d+', headline).group()
```

**or**

You must remove the forward slashes present in your regex.

```
re.findall(r'^\D*(\d+)', headline)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
re.search('[0-9]+', headline).group()
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution without regex (not necessarily better):

```
import string

no_digits = string.printable[10:]

headline = "redirectDetail('27184','2 -New-York-Explorer-Pass')"
trans = str.maketrans(no_digits, " "*len(no_digits))

print(headline.translate(trans).split()[0])
>>> 27184
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to get the first number in the string and the currency too, I tried all solutions, some returned the number without a dot, others returned the number I did like this

```
priceString = "Rs249.5"

def advancedSplit(unformatedtext):
    custom_numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    priceList = []
    str_length = len(unformatedtext)
    index = 0
    for l in range(len(unformatedtext)):
        if unformatedtext[l] in custom_numbers:
            price = unformatedtext[slice(l, len(unformatedtext))]
            currency = unformatedtext[slice(0,l)]
            priceList.append(currency)
            priceList.append(price)
            break
        elif index == str_length:
            priceList.append("")
            priceList.append("unformatedtext")
            break
        else:
            continue
            
        index += 1
    return priceList
print(advancedSplit(priceString))
```

to make sure the list will always has len of 2 I added the elif in case the priceString was just "249.5" because I'm using this in web scrape