# How do I find the first number of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a very basic question ..sorry....I'm a newbie.
A few specifications:
-The string is an arithmetic expression.
-It would love the output to return the number i.e a 2 digit number or 3 digit 
 number depending on the string.
For example if string is "12+3-5/6"
Then the output should be 12.
I have tried this:

```
import re
s = "12*9-6/4"
m = re.search("\d" , s)
if m:
    print(s[m.start()])
else:
    print("try again")
```

But this outputs the first number it sees and not the whole 2 digit number. How do I change it?

```
input = '123abc456def'
output = re.findall(r'^\d+', input)
```

But this returns the value in square brackets. Ht do I just get a number.

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571348/getting-only-the-first-number-from-string-in-python

Comment: You should split the string based on the operations ('*', '+', '-') and you can have an array of all the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **re.match**

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "12*9-6/4"
m = re.match("(?P<first>\d+)" , s)
if m:
    print(m.group('first'))
else:
    print("try again")
```

**Output:**

```
12
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with re so I didnt know about the match function. Now that you told me this I have read about it online and learned it. Thanks once again.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Without `regex`, you can use `next` with a generator comprehension and `enumerate`:

```
s = '12*9-6/4'

idx = next((i for i, j in enumerate(s) if not j.isdigit()), len(s))

res = int(s[:idx])  # 12
```

**Explanation**

- The generator comprehension iterates over an enumerated `s`, yielding `(0, '1')`, `(1, '2')`, `(2, '*')`, etc.
- With `next`, we find the first instance `j.isdigit` evaluates to true for a character in `s`.
- We then extract the index `i`; if no such character exists, we use the length of the string.
- Finally, we use `s[:idx]` to slice the string up to but not including the calculated index.

Comment: I am not familiar with this method. Sorry. I have no idea what the 2nd and 3rd lines of code mean.

Comment: @Shesps, I have updated with an explanation.

Comment: Thank you... now I get it!!!